# PostgreSQL triggers stopped working

Tags: postgresql

I had to reinstall my Hyper-V Windows server, so I took a schema backup of my PostgreSQL database.

Afterwards, I imported the schema backup. Everything looks good on the surface. All tables, functions, triggers and sequences are there. Except that for some reason trigger functions no longer do anything.

I have two triggers, this is one of the two.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER t_update_modified
      AFTER UPDATE
      ON queue
      FOR EACH ROW
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_modified();

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_modified()
      RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$BEGIN
        NEW.modified = now();
        Return NEW;
    END;$BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100;
    ALTER FUNCTION update_modified()
      OWNER TO postgres;
    GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION update_modified() TO postgres;
    REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION update_modified() FROM public;
```

I added `RAISE WARNING`statements into the code to check if the functions actually get executed and how far they go, I confirmed that the functions do in fact get executed and they execute all the way to the `RETURN` statement.

I also added `EXCEPTION` statement to catch any exceptions that might get thrown, but no such thing happens.

The function above is supposed to update time-stamp of a column modified, but nothing happens. Both of my two trigger functions used to work on the older virtual machine. `postgres` user has all permissions on the table in question, and has execute permissions on the trigger function.

And this is the second trigger:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER t_new_task
      AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF status
      ON queue
      FOR EACH ROW
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE new_task();

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_task()
      RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$BEGIN
        NOTIFY newtask;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;$BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE LEAKPROOF
      COST 100;
    ALTER FUNCTION new_task()
      OWNER TO postgres;
    GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION new_task() TO postgres;
    GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION new_task() TO public;
```

Like earlier, `NOTIFY`does nothing. No client that is connected receives any notification. This too used to work on the old virtual machine.

Nothing related to the trigger functions gets logged to the logfile, unless I add `RAISE WARNING` statements to them.

I've never had this kind of problem before with triggers. Does anybody have a clue what is going on here?

I did re-create these triggers too, but that didn't solve the problem either.

Update: I created a new database just for testing a trigger. Trigger didn't work there either, so this problem is affecting the entire PostgreSQL server. I'm about ready to pull my hair out.

Update 2: Reinstalled PostgreSQL server and deleted its data. Triggers still non-functional.

Comment: Configuration item `set log_min_messages = NOTIFY;`

Comment: It is actually `notice`, but nothing is logged when trigger is executed. Well, unless I add `RAISE WARNING` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a BEFORE trigger. In an AFTER trigger, it's too late to modify row values.
If you think it worked before and it's a matter of environment, you most likely made a confusion interpreting results at some point, because (as you mention in your update), it's a general thing.

Here is how it's mentioned in the manual, in
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/trigger-definition.html

> The return value is ignored for row-level triggers fired after an
>   operation, and so they can return NULL.

A more complete comparison of BEFORE/AFTER follows a few paragraphs after:

> Typically, row-level BEFORE triggers are used for checking or
>   modifying the data that will be inserted or updated. For example, a
>   BEFORE trigger might be used to insert the current time into a
>   timestamp column, or to check that two elements of the row are
>   consistent. Row-level AFTER triggers are most sensibly used to
>   propagate the updates to other tables, or make consistency checks
>   against other tables. The reason for this division of labor is that an
>   AFTER trigger can be certain it is seeing the final value of the row,
>   while a BEFORE trigger cannot; there might be other BEFORE triggers
>   firing after it. If you have no specific reason to make a trigger
>   BEFORE or AFTER, the BEFORE case is more efficient, since the
>   information about the operation doesn't have to be saved until end of
>   statement

Comment: As you can see, I have two functions. BEFORE is what the timestamp trigger should use and AFTER is what the notify trigger should use. As I had been trying to get them working, I must have left the timestamp trigger as AFTER.

In any case, unfortunately this did not solve the problem. Neither trigger still works as expected, regardless of whether they are BEFORE or AFTER.

Comment: @KeeperB5: please update your question to reflect your changes. As it is now, it's an `after` update or insert trigger so the changes to NEW are ignored as documented.

Comment: After a good night's sleep I took another look at this. I triple-checked `t_update_modified` uses `BEFORE UPDATE`, and `t_new_task` uses `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE`. And lo and behold, now the triggers work. Although I could've sworn the triggers were set-up like that to begin with before I started messing with them to solve the problem. In any case, it's now all good and I am going to accept your answer as the solution.